# Can QuartzServer NET decrypts connection string in config file?

Tags: encryption, quartz.net

I'm using Quartz.Server.exe 2.X as job executor.
I'm using Quartz.Server.exe.config to configure quartz.

```
<quartz >
    <add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceName" value="AlyCE_LROScheduler" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.type" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.useProperties" value="true" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SqlServerDelegate, Quartz" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix" value="QUARTZ_" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.dataSource" value="defaultDS" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.lockHandler.type" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.UpdateLockRowSemaphore, Quartz" />
    <add key="quartz.dataSource.defaultDS.provider" value="SqlServer-20" />
    <add key="quartz.dataSource.defaultDS.connectionString" value="my connection string to encrypt/decrypt" />
</quartz>
```

All works fine. Now I'd like to encrypt the connection string for security reason.

Is there a way to let Quartz.Server.exe to understand encrypted connection string?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved.
I removed the connection string quartz property and I added the connectionProvider.type property, that let me to override the standard Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.Common.DbProvider.

So I am able to decrypt my connection string.

So my config looks like this:

```
<quartz >
    <!-- thread pool info -->
    <add key="quartz.threadPool.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz" />
    <!-- job store info -->
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.type" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.useProperties" value="true" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SqlServerDelegate, Quartz" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix" value="QUARTZ_" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.dataSource" value="defaultDS" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.lockHandler.type" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.UpdateLockRowSemaphore, Quartz" />
    <add key="quartz.dataSource.defaultDS.connectionProvider.type" value="MyDll.MyDbProvider, MyDll" />
</quartz>
<connectionStrings>
    <add key="myConnString" connectionString="crypted"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Then I create new class library project where I created this class:

```
public class MyDbProvider : DbProvider
{
    public MyDbProvider() : base("SqlServer-20", MyHelper.GetConnectionString()) { }
}

public static class MyHelper
{
    public static string GetConnectionString()
    {
        //here i decrypt my connection string from app.config file
    }
}
```

MyDll.dll must be in the same directory of Quartz.Server.exe .

Hope this can help someone!